# Identify the cable connector

Tags: cable

Please identify this cable connector by model/part number/supplier.  It is a cable between a control box and microprocessor.  One photo for scale shows the connector next to an RJ45.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's no standard network adapter, likely not network at all.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Ultra low profile 8P8C connector with a cable that has a normal 8P8C RJ45 on the other end. 

https://www.wayconn.com/non-shielded-8p8c-ultra-low-profile-rj45/

Probably came with some special equipment that has to have a low profile chassis to fit in a special application/environment.